# Exclude given directory from git add

Tags: git

I have applied git to `/var/www/classes`.  I would like git to track all files in it included those in `/var/www/classes/dont_include` (i.e. I don't want to use `.gitignore` to exclude this directory).

How do I add (stage) all files except those in `/var/www/classes/dont_include`?

```
/var/www/classes
/var/www/classes/included1
/var/www/classes/included2
/var/www/classes/dont_include
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use .gitignore?

Comment: I do use .gitignore, but I don't want to use it on this particular directory as I wish to track all changes.  I just want to add it for a different commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible way is using --assume-unchanged, as per [github's help](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).

Before adding, do

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged /var/www/classes/dont_include
```

After committing, do

```
$git update-index --no-assume-unchanged /var/www/classes/dont_include
```

Comment: Thanks Kathy.  Definitely does what I want, but so does Tim's.  Would you recommend this approach or his?

Comment: Which ever works best for your workflow. My approach works well if you're going to do a number of commits this way and don't want to keep adding manually, but you have to remember the --no-assume-unchanged when you're finished. Some days there's not enough coffee in the world to make that happen. :)

--assume-unchanged *is* very useful when you have, for example, files that are distributed with a repo that need to remain with the repo, but don't need to get recommitted when they change.

Comment: Thanks Kathy,  I feel they are both equally good answers, but this one will likely work best for my workflow for what I want to do today.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of these

1. Add the other folders manually

   ```
   $git add included1/ included2/
   ```
2. Add everything and remove the unwanted folder from the staging area

   ```
   $git add .
   $git reset -- dont_include/
   ```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Definitely does what I want, but so does Kathy's.  Would you recommend this approach or hers?

Comment: I would recommend my 2nd approach, because it has the easiest looking and easiest to remember commands (so it's more beginner friendly). The 1st would be even easier but in case you have 180 folders you want to include that could take a while ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you don't want to ignore that directory, rather adding in another commit you should either manually specify files/directory or add all than remove that directory.

If you've a lot of files/directory, specify each one would take a lot of time.
So removing that folder is much faster and easier. You can do that from `/var/www/classes` as follow:

```
$ git add .
$ git reset -- dont_include
```

In your staging area you'll now find everything but `dont_include`